# From java application to applet?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, applet

I never worked with applets and have the following questions:

- can an existing Java Desktop App be ported to an Applet by just providing a different interface? Can I reuse everything that's behind the GUI (services, injections, databases)?
- is the same possible for Java EE applications? Just provide a different UI and reuse the rest of the code?

Comment: *"From java application to applet?"*  NOOOooooo... Instead launch the frame using [Java Web Start](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/java-web-start/info).  And in case you should question my ability to offer such a plaintiff cry, check [top answer providers for applet](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/applet/topusers) ***&*** [top answer providers for JWS](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/java-web-start/topusers)  - (& do the math - I know what I'm talking about here).

Comment: is an application with JWS running within the browser, or is it more like a desktop app when running? I would need the first one...

Comment: *"running within the browser"*  Why, exactly?  What does the browser window wrapper actually provide to the app.?  Don't get me wrong, there are some types of use-cases that *justify* that an applet be embedded, but they are very rare.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basicly you just have to embed the JFrame, or whatever you used before, in an Class,which is extending an Applet. No you can´t use everything, there are some security restrictions for Applets(acces to the filesystem for example) until they are getting signed.

Comment: *"just have to embed the JFrame, or whatever you used before, in an Class,which is extending an Applet"*  A `JApplet` would be the correct applet container for a Swing GUI.

Answer (score 0):

The UI, etc. for the most part is 'reusable', but the applet is also subject to stricter Sandboxing; the applet is limited to only the permissions that the user allows and/or additions to the JVM settings on the user machine.  (There are also restrictions on port access for applets for things like database connections - and possible firewall considerations.

So, the answer is a "yes, but there is still a lot of work.  Get to know what kind of work that would be based on your user base.

Answer (score 0):

Basically when you are making applets you can't use frames or a menu. You should use panels and work on them. Most of things after that are simple and same.